# populating a new column based on certain conditions and shift operation and group by

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks something like

```
LastName Date ObjectCol1 ObjectCol2 NumCol1 NumCol2 CurrentState ExpectedState
ABC      March                                            A1              A2     
ABC      June                                             A1              A2
XYZ      March                                            A2              A2
XYZ      June                                             A2              A2
XYZ      July                                             A2              A2
AAA      March                                            D3              D2
AAA      June                                             D2              D1  
DEF      March                                            C1              C1
DEF      June                                             C2              C3
DEF      July                                             C3              C3
```

I would like to create a new column such that for the last name, (and if the Date value is not the max date for that last name), then if Intermediate 2 == Intermediate 1 (for the next subsequent date value for that last name), then the new column value would be ..say "Hit", else "Miss"
If the date value is the max date, then the column value would be "Yet to be seen"

So the result would look something like

```
LastName Date ObjectCol1 ObjectCol2 NumCol1 NumCol2 CurrentState ExpectedState   Result
ABC      March                                            A1              A2      Miss (because A2 here != Intermediate 1 value in the next row)
ABC      June                                             A1              A2      Yet to be seen
XYZ      March                                            A2              A2      Hit
XYZ      June                                             A2              A2      Hit
XYZ      July                                             A2              A2      Yet to be seen
AAA      March                                            D3              D2      Hit
AAA      June                                             D2              D1      Yet to be seen
DEF      March                                            C1              C1      Miss
DEF      June                                             C2              C3      Hit
DEF      July                                             C3              C3      Yet to be seen
```

Comment: I don't get why for lastname `ABC`, the two `Intermediate2` values are `A2`.

Comment: Perhaps the column name " Intermediate" is misleading.. It is in reality just some state of prediction ..So A2 for ABC in Intermediate 2 is correct.
Its just like.. some algo predicted ABC as Dead.. but in June it was still Alive.. And algo still predicted for next date as Dead.

Comment: @QuangHoang: Perhaps i'll change the column name to avoid the confusion

Comment: This is like asking why the data is the way it is before/without knowing anything on the data.. I dont think your question is any meaningful

Comment: So, the `CurrentState` and `ExpectedStated` are given, and you want result?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in the question/description

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Pre-result'] = df.groupby(['LastName'])['CurrentState '].shift(-1)

df['Result'] = np.where(df['Pre-result'] == df['ExpectedState'], "Hit", "Miss")

df['Result'] = np.where(df['Pre-result'].isna(), "Yet to be seen", df['Result'])

del df['Pre-result']


LastName Date ObjectCol1 ObjectCol2 NumCol1 NumCol2 CurrentState ExpectedState   Result
ABC      March                                            A1              A2      Miss (because A2 here != Intermediate 1 value in the next row)
ABC      June                                             A1              A2      Yet to be seen
XYZ      March                                            A2              A2      Hit
XYZ      June                                             A2              A2      Hit
XYZ      July                                             A2              A2      Yet to be seen
AAA      March                                            D3              D2      Hit
AAA      June                                             D2              D1      Yet to be seen
DEF      March                                            C1              C1      Miss
DEF      June                                             C2              C3      Hit
DEF      July                                             C3              C3      Yet to be seen
```